# How to run a python script on client side without demanding permissions or requiring special installations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I have a windows application built with progress openedge technology.
I have created a python script to generate an excel file but I need to deploy it to the client and im afraid of requiring special permissions on the client side if I compile it to .exe and attempt to run it.

Can someone suggest me a method to be able to integrate python with my project smoothly without breaking anything?

Comment: What kind of _special permissions_ are you referring to?

Comment: Have you tried creating the exe that you refer to and testing to see if it needs any special permissions?

Comment: im afraid it occurs on the client side, and for example if they denied third parties programs from running or anything like that.

Answer (score 2):

You could compile it on your own machine then try to run it while logged in as a guest user. If a guest account can run it without complaints it will probably run fine on the client machine.

This is crude because you still haven't tested all possible client platforms (unless you're talking about **one specific** client), also we don't know  what's inside your script.

Use [icacls](https://superuser.com/a/106184) to set appropriate permissions of your compiled script before shipping.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the special permissions thing, but is it possible for you to turn your script into a CGI program and stick it on your webserver, or wrapper it with WebSpeed? Then your app could call a web service to get the .xls file.